# preg_match text that isn't inside or between html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a blog in wordpress and am trying to improve internal linking.  I have a l csv with key words and the associate page I want to link to for those key words.  What I did is pull the wp_posts table and wrote a script to loop through the content for posts and matched the first occurrence of each key word on the page and wrapped it with a link.  This worked great except that it match words in titles and other links.  Wasn't a big problem to fix at the time as I only had 30 posts to skim and clean up.  Now I want to do this again but I have 500 posts.  The function I am using to match the first occurrence is:

```
function str_replace_first($from, $to, $subject) {
    $from = '/(\s|\")('.preg_quote($from, '/').')(s|es|d|ed)?(\s|\,|\.|\:|\;|\'|\"|\!)/i';
    $from = str_replace(' ', '\s', $from);
    return preg_replace($from, '$1' . '<a href="http://www.heropay.com/glossary/' . $to . '">$2$3</a>$4', $subject, 1);
}
```

The function takes the word I am looking for and wraps it in a regex.  The regex is looking for a word that is followed and proceeded by white space or punctuation.  I need to expand this regex to not match text that is in a tag (like a word in the alt text of a image) or between two tags (like the middle word in between 2 H2 tags).  For example:

```
<h1>Some text here</h1>
<img src="http://example.com/img/text.png" alt="Some text here" />
 some more text here.
```

In the HTML above if my term I wanted to link was the word "text" the function should return:

```
<h1>Some text here</h1>
<img src="http://example.com/img/text.png" alt="Some text here" />
 some more <a href="http://example.com/text">text</a> here.
```

It would skip over the "text" in the h1 and the alt tag of the image. I have tried modifying my matching regex to:

```
/[^<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>]?(\s|\")('.preg_quote($from, '/').')(s|es|d|ed)?(\s|\,|\.|\:|\;|\'|\"|\!)[^<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>]?/i
```

this would try and catch the html tags but this seems not to work.

Comment: A wall of text but not much examples. If I understand it correct, the only thing you need to do is wrap the subject in strip_tags(). `strip_tags($subject);` this will remove all html tags and you are left with only real text.

Comment: i think the easiest way is to clean up all html tags and its contents first, then do what you need after that. here's a sample snippet for removing html and its contents http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#86964